# formatting dictionary structure in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have an input list of the form:

`d=[{'CLIENT': ['A','B','C']},{'ROW':['1','2','3']},{'KP':['ROM','MON','SUN']}]`

I want the output to look like:

```
S=[{'CLIENT':'A','ROW':'1','KP':'ROM'},
   {'CLIENT':'B','ROW':'2','KP':'MON'},
   {'CLIENT':'C','ROW':'3','KP':'SUN'},]
```

How can i do this in python?
the input element dictionaries' keys may change, so I don't want to hardcode them in the code as well.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

With a little cheating by letting `pandas` do the work:

Setup:

```
from collections import ChainMap
import pandas as pd
d = [{'CLIENT': ['A','B','C']},{'ROW':['1','2','3']},{'KP':['ROM','MON','SUN']}]
```

Solution:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(dict(ChainMap(*d))).to_dict(orient='records')
```

Result:

```
[{'KP': 'ROM', 'ROW': '1', 'CLIENT': 'A'},
 {'KP': 'MON', 'ROW': '2', 'CLIENT': 'B'},
 {'KP': 'SUN', 'ROW': '3', 'CLIENT': 'C'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Manually it would look like this

```
S=[{} for i in range(len(d))]
i = 0
for dict in d:
    for k, v in dict.items(): # Always 1
        for value in v:
            S[i][k]=value
            i+=1
        i=0
print(S)
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the key from the each dictionary and the values, then `zip()` them together into a new `dict()`:

```
data = [{'CLIENT': ['A', 'B', 'C']}, {'ROW': ['1', '2', '3']}, {'KP': ['ROM', 'MON', 'SUN']}]

new_keys = [list(d.keys())[0] for d in data]
new_values = zip(*[val for d in data for val in d.values()])

s = [dict(zip(new_keys, val)) for val in new_values]
print(s)
```

Output:

```
[{'CLIENT': 'A', 'ROW': '1', 'KP': 'ROM'}, 
 {'CLIENT': 'B', 'ROW': '2', 'KP': 'MON'}, 
 {'CLIENT': 'C', 'ROW': '3', 'KP': 'SUN'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it, by making use of the builtin `zip()` function a couple of times, and the `chain()` function of the `itertools` module.

The idea is to use `zip()` first to group together the lists' items (`('A', '1', 'ROM'), ('B', '2', 'MON'), ('C', '3', 'SUN')`) as we desire, and the keys of each dictionary `('CLIENT', 'ROW', 'KP')`).

Then, we can use a list comprehension, iterating over the just created `values` list, and zipping its content together with the `keys` tuple, to finally produce the dictionaries that will be stored within the `s` list

```
from itertools import chain


d = [{'CLIENT': ['A','B','C']},{'ROW':['1','2','3']},{'KP':['ROM','MON','SUN']}]
keys, *values = zip(*[chain(dict_.keys(), *dict_.values()) for dict_ in d])
s = [dict(zip(keys, tuple_)) for tuple_ in values]
```

The content of `s` will be:

```
[
    {'CLIENT': 'A', 'ROW': '1', 'KP': 'ROM'},
    {'CLIENT': 'B', 'ROW': '2', 'KP': 'MON'},
    {'CLIENT': 'C', 'ROW': '3', 'KP': 'SUN'}
]
```